# Should coefficients in Logistic and Linear regression be the same?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, logistic-regression

I Have a code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3,4,7,8,9,10,12,13])
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1,0,1,1,1,1,0])
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["x"] = x
df["y"] = y
lm = LinearRegression()
lr = LogisticRegression()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.drop('y',axis=1), 
                                                    df['y'], test_size=0.30, 
                                                    random_state=101)
lm.fit(X_train, y_train)
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

and i would like to see coefficients so i did:

```
print(lm.coef_)
print(lm.intercept_)
print(lr.coef_)
print(lr.intercept_)
```

but the output is:

```
[0.03978495]
0.05268817204301074
[[0.20732702]]
[-2.29481756]
```

I cant understand why they are not the same, according to the wikipedia, the coefficients from linear regression y = a0 + a1x are taken to the formula for Logistic Regression y = 1/(1 + e^(-(a0 + a1x)), but Python did something that i cant understand.

Comment: Why would you expect the coefficients to be the same? You are fitting fundamentally different models on the same dataset. I think wikipedia was merely saying that the logistic regression is just a sigmoid applied to a linear regression model, not that the coefficients of the trained models are equivalent.

If you wanted to verify, just plug in your coefficients of your linear model, into your logistic regression model, and see what kind of predictions you get. It will most definitely not be the same as the logistic regression predictions.

Comment: Okay, but if we use linear regression coefficient to build a logistic regressin they shouldn't be the same? Hence how to compute logistic regression coefficient? And what excatly they are? a0 and a1 in my example?

Comment: Yes. Also, a0=lr.intercept_[0], a1=lr.coef_[0][0] (if I indexed well, now I am working with matlab)